# Angular 5 iframe set width and height same as its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a lot of iframes and I want that each of the `iframe` would have it's `height` and `width` same as it's content.

For example : if `iframe` content is `1300x300`, I need that `iframe` would be `1300x300` on my page. I am loading iframes from my domain.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code and check

// add in had

```
<script>
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

//change iframe

```
<iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" />
```

Comment: I am gettint error : -LB_1v_F9EZ67x_myUKU:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: I am loading it from a .zip file in my database.

Comment: change script position in footer and check i think problem in you other j query conflict with script code

Comment: Nah, it's blocking because I can't reach iframe height if it's content in another domain